# I used the replace() function of Python, but it isn't giving the desired results

Tags: python, pandas

I have a user's dataset in which I have data of dates in the occurred_at column, in text format. In it, I have dates in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` and `dd-mm-yyyy` both.

I need to make them similar, so I thought of using the `replace()` function. But it isn't giving me the desired result. There are still dates with both format present. Can someone please help me with this or suggest me some other way to achieve the task?

Comment: Add a small, working example script that demonstrates the problem. A dataframe with just a couple of rows and columns will do.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please remember to read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your post accordingly, because right now the claim that "it isn't giving me the desired result" doesn't tell folks anything: what is "it"? What is "the desired result"? Where is the code that you wrote so folks can see what you did?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the problem description, I think you are confusing `Series.replace` with `Series.str.replace`. The first function replaces the values, while the second one replaces letters in a cell value:

[image: replace example]

- [pandas.Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)
- [pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `'occurred_at'` is the column with date values in text format;

```
df['occurred_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['occurred_at'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).